# Applying taxes on Satchmo's cart total price

Tags: django, satchmo, django-apps

I can't seem to apply a tax value on the cart total value even though
I :

1. activated the "By Country/Area" tax module.
2. added my country/region tax rate.
3. checked the "Show With tax included" checkbox.

[here's attached a screenshot of the on-going problems](http://www.picoodle.com/view.php?img=/3/1/13/f_errorm_2003f36.png&srv=img34), I've selected
the areas where something's fishy.

So basically, the cart shows "With tax included" but doesn't calculate
it neither on the item or the total. The checkout shows some tax
calculation in the "Item Ordered" but its total is not the right
amount. It's also not displaying in the "total" fieldset.

I changed the templates a bit to make it look a little better but I
didn't change all those satchmo filters/tags.

here's the template for [base_cart.html](http://dpaste.com/hold/108581/)

And here's the checkout template ([order_details.html](http://dpaste.com/hold/108582/))

** I also posted this question on the [satchmo google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/satchmo-users/browse_thread/thread/4ae29a735e2b2079) but I thought it might be worth it to post it here as well since [google has now more than a million stackoverflow pages](http://www.google.ca/search?hl=fr&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hs=kaS&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com&btnG=Rechercher&meta=). :P

Comment: Are you asking for help with hacking the source for Satchmo, or general Satchmo configuration help here?

Comment: I was looking for a general Satchmo configuration help and Bruce Kroeze (one of satchmo's dev guy) has answered my question on their google groups. I just added the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to make my products taxable using the checkbox and the selectbox in the admin section.

Then to make it calculate the tax only on the cart's total, I just need to uncheck the "Show with tax included" in the Tax Settings.